# Two tables - SELECT TOP from one of the tables for each row in second table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a report which uses two tables.

`tblContacts`
`tblCalls`
I want to pull the TOP 1 from `tblCalls` for each row in `tblContacts`.  I'm not entirely sure how to go about doing this.  I tried to use JOINS but the only way that logically makes sense to me is where I get an error fired back telling me it's an ambiguous OUTER JOIN.  So I tried to make two different queries to accomplish this, and in the end, it still only pulled TOP 1 for BOTH tables, so I'm not entirely sure where I'm going wrong.

I've tried a number of different SQL statements, and even though it doesn't work, this is the "*closest*" I've come thus far (The TOP 1 isn't working at all):

```
SELECT tblCalls.ID, tblCalls.[Call Time], tblCalls.NextContact, tblCalls.Subject, tblCalls.Notes, [First Name] & " " & [Last Name] AS FullName, tblContacts.[Mobile Phone], tblContacts.[Home Phone], tblContacts.[E-mail Address]
FROM tblCalls INNER JOIN tblContacts ON tblCalls.Contact = tblContacts.ID
GROUP BY tblCalls.ID, tblCalls.[Call Time], tblCalls.NextContact, tblCalls.Subject, tblCalls.Notes, [First Name] & " " & [Last Name], tblContacts.[Mobile Phone], tblContacts.[Home Phone], tblContacts.[E-mail Address];
```

This shows all the Call records in `tblCalls`.  When I adjust the query to show TOP 1, it obviously only shows one record in total.

Additionally, just in case this becomes a problem down the road, I adding an "Archive" column to `tblContacts` and those records designated as "True" won't be listed on this report at all.  This part should be easy, but just in case it's something that might break something later on, I figured I'd add it to the question.

Thanks!

Comment: The MySQL tag was an accident.  Fixed.  Not exactly sure what about my single SQL statement isn't a minimal reproducible example outside of my previous statement regarding the mix-up with the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get the last call for each contact is with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT c.* FROM tblCalls c
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM tblCalls cc
  WHERE cc.Contact = c.Contact AND cc.[Call Time] > c.[Call Time]
)
```

So you can join it to the table:

```
SELECT
  c.ID, c.[Call Time], c.NextContact, c.Subject, c.Notes, 
  t.[First Name] & " " & t.[Last Name] AS FullName, 
  t.[Mobile Phone], t.[Home Phone], t.[E-mail Address] 
FROM tblContacts t LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT c.* FROM tblCalls c
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1 FROM tblCalls cc
    WHERE cc.Contact = c.Contact AND cc.[Call Time] > c.[Call Time]
  )
) c ON c.Contact = t.ID
```

Comment: This is really close!  It does list a single entry for each entry in ```tblCalls``` but it's also listing ALL records from ```tblContacts```.  I tried to add "Is Not Null" to ```tblCalls.ID``` and it fires back an error; "HAVING clause (Not C.ID Is Null) without grouping or aggregation".  Does this mean I need to group on ID?  Ideally, I want to group on ''FullName".

Comment: If you don't want all the rows from tblContacts change the LEFT join to INNER.

Comment: I did, and accidently un-accepted it (I was clickin' willy nilly, sorry lol).  Fixed!  Thanks again for the help!